# How access form data as dict in streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to be able to access the form data of a streamlit form as a collected dictonary object on the form. I know I can put it into seperate variables, but my code will be much nicer and easier to generalize if I can access it directly on the form object and it seems strange if it is not posible.

```
form = st.form(key="my_form")
form.text_input("input 1")
# Allot of more inputs
def submit():
    requests.post("localhost:5000/form-submit", data=prepare_for_backend(form.data))
form.form_submit_button("Submit", on_click=submit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit does not package the contents of the form into a self-contained dictionary for you. You can assign keys to each of the objects in your form and access their data through session state if you want. Otherwise you can save the widget output values into a dictionary directly.

It's important to note that with a form, both the values associated to the widgets in session state and their outputs do not reflect the user's changes until after they click the form submit button.

```py
import streamlit as st

form1_dict = {}
with st.form('form1'):
    form1_dict['a'] = st.text_input('a')
    form1_dict['b'] = st.text_input('b')
    st.form_submit_button('Submit Form 1')

st.write(form1_dict)

with st.form('form2'):
    st.text_input('a', key='form2_a')
    st.text_input('b', key='form2_b')
    st.form_submit_button('Submit Form 2')

form2_dict = {}
for key in st.session_state:
    if key.startswith('form2_'):
        form2_dict[key.removeprefix('form2_')] = st.session_state[key]

st.write(form2_dict)
```